# is there a pdf viewer that doesn't take over the screen in presenter mode?

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

I am looking for a PDF viewer that just shows the PDF in presenter mode (on OSx), but in a small window, not one that takes over the screen in presentation mode as Preview. I just want to share that window on Teams and be able to still see the rest of my screen. Anything like that exists?

Comment: Can you define what you mean by 'Presenter mode'? Do you mean like a Powerpoint/Keynote slideshow? That's just single-page view, isn't it?

Comment: I use Preview to view pdf's and it doesn't take over the entire screen.  It just opens to the same size window that I last used it.

Comment: I don't have preview taking over with presenter view (whatever that is) - comes up in a small window the normal size I last used...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Présentation.app](http://iihm.imag.fr/blanch/software/osx-presentation/). It opens a presentation window with no decorations and not in full screen. Plus a presenter window, which you move to a corner (but unfortunately you cannot hide it).